# Are there non-vegan water sources?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan

It would seem obvious that in modern society (USA) your water comes to the tap without involving animal exploitation.  But most municipal (city) water supplies involve several types of treatment before it is delivered to your water tap.

Are there methods of treating water, that do or don't involve animal exploitation? If so how can we identify vegan or non-vegan water supplies?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[In a similar vein to sugar](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/39/is-some-sugar-not-vegan), bone char is also used to filter water. This works in the same way normal charcoal filtering does, with the water passed through the bone char.

In the US, this has been mostly phased out. [(source)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1920070/)  It's possible that your water is still filtered with bone char however, and there's no real way to be sure short of asking your city or county's municipal department.

In addition, bone char is still used in some commercial water filters, such as for refrigerators with built-in water dispensers.  Some brands, such as [Brita](https://www.brita.com/), advertise the lack of bone char. They should be safe.

So yes, even though it's not common, though it could be common in commercial water filters.