# Vegan egg nog for the holidays?

Tags: veganism, dairy-substitutes, recipe-request, egg-substitutes

With the holidays coming up this question seems relevant, so here it goes, would it be possible to make a vegan egg nog?

Comment: What characteristics of egg nog are you trying to retain -- general flavor, mouthfeel, etc.?

Comment: General flavor mostly as the question is for the benefit of my stepsister who’s a vegetarian.

Comment: @AbrahamRay I see that the question asks about the vegan egg nog, but if this is for your stepsister, as a vegetarian, she probably won't have much trouble with eggs. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Traditional egg nog uses eggs, dairy, sugar, booze, and nutmeg. All of these are actually (lacto-ovo) vegetarian ingredients.

If you want to make a fully vegan "egg" nog, eggs and dairy can't be used. The *good* news, though, is that those aren't the primary flavor characteristics of the drink! I don't get nostalgic about drinking raw eggs, I'm interested in the nutmeg and sweetness -- and you can still include liquor, [sugar](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/39/is-some-sugar-not-vegan), and nutmeg.

There are a lot of options available for replacing that "creamy" base of eggs and cream: non-dairy milks, tofu, cashew cream, and so on. (If your traditional egg nog is one that includes a foamy top layer, find a vegan whipped cream alternative.)

One of my personal favorite versions is Tori Avey's [Veggnog](https://toriavey.com/toris-kitchen/veggnog-vegan-eggnog/), but I'd encourage you to [search and try a few different options](https://www.google.com/search?q=vegan%20egg%20nog).

Comment: Personally I prefer the non-alcoholic version of egg nog myself, but that’s just me.

Comment: In that case I recommend rum extract; I do find it to be a helpful flavor (I used it to make non-alcoholic nog when pregnant!)

Comment: When I checked out the veggnog recipe I thought it looked great!

Comment: Hope your stepsister likes it too! :)