# Is this coffee syrup recipe vegan or vegetarian?

Tags: is-it-vegan, food

I would like to know whether this coffee syrup recipe is vegan or just vegetarian. Below is the recipe:

> **Coffee syrup ingredients:**
>   2 cups of sugar
>   1 cup of coffee
>
> **Directions:**
>   Put the sugar into the coffee
>
> Boil the mixture untill it reaches a thick syrup state
>
> To make into a liquid coffee put 1-2 tablespoons of the syrup into hot water and stir until it completely dissolves

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on what can be seen in the recipe it might well be vegan as there are no visible animal ingredients used.

The one problem that can render it non-vegan (and arguably even non-vegetarian) would be the sugar that you use to make the syrup. During the production of sugar, bone char of animals is sometimes used and this makes the sugar non-vegan and non-vegetarian. If youwant to use sugar that would not use bone char, I suggest you to have a look at the answers to [this question](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1317/how-can-i-identify-whether-the-sugar-in-a-packaged-food-is-vegan-or-not).

To conclude, **the recipe in itself is clearly vegan but make sure you use the right sugar**. I hope you'll enjoy the coffee syrup :).